Where can I find high resolution sea surface wind data?
I have been looking for high temporal and spatial resolution surface wind data.
I want to use it for competitive sailing simulation, so the temporal resolution should be less than 10 s, the special resolution should be less than 10 m, and the extent of the domain should be in the range of 1X1 Km.
I guess this should be LIDAR data, but I can't find such a dataset.

At such high resolutions, and with 1x1km coverage, I am doubtful that such data exists from measurements. While LIDAR could provide the resolution, as you suggest - if processed and saved with that 10 sec time step - it would take many LIDAR deployments to cover 1x1 km at the low altitude that would be relevant for sailing.
The way that you might be able to get a dataset like this is from modelling. Somebody may have produced modelled outputs with this sort of resolution, validated by a smaller number of measurements. If you are very lucky they might have done it for the area you are interested in. But i'm afraid I wouldn't know where to suggest looking.

Yes, I started thinking of creating synthetic data.
However I think such data now exists (or at least possible to measure). Have a look here:
https://youtu.be/M6FlT62PQks?si=cl9rIV7172jir5Cr

@yairsuari ok, that's pretty cool. Sounds as though they're using horizontal LIDAR to drive a numerical model. I don't know for sure, but I suspect that that may only currently exist for the location of this year's Americas Cup ;-)
